# Oracle SQL view with COUNT, AVG columns

Tags: sql, oracle, view, inner-join, average

I have 3 tables, item, item_cagegory and category. Item and item_category are linked in item_id, item_category and category are linked on category_id.

I am creating a view that lists the IDs and names of the categories, the number of items in each category and calculates the average rental rate for all items in that category.

All my code seems to work, except AVG_RATE which just seems to spit out the rate (instead of the average rate per category). Any suggestions how to do this?

```
CREATE VIEW V_CATEGORY AS   
    SELECT DISTINCT category.category_id, category.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_category 
        WHERE item_category.category_id = category.category_id) 
        AS items_in_category, 
    (SELECT AVG(item.rate) FROM item_category 
        WHERE item_CATEGORY.item_id = item.item_id 
        GROUP BY item_category.category_id) 
        AS avg_rate
        FROM category
    INNER JOIN item_category ON category.category_id = item_CATEGORY.category_id
    INNER JOIN item ON item_category.item_id = item.item_id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write the `select` like this:

```
SELECT 
  category.category_id, 
  category.name,
  COUNT(item.item_id) as items_in_category,
  AVG(item.rate) as avg_rate
FROM
  category
INNER JOIN 
  item_category ON category.category_id = item_CATEGORY.category_id
INNER JOIN 
  item ON item_category.item_id = item.item_id
GROUP BY
  category.category_id, 
  category.name
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately when I try to create the view with that select statement, it fails with "ORA-00937: not a single group function".

Comment: @reallybadatmath, I forgot to add the group by clause...should work now.